# git clone - https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf

Tags: python, spacy, huggingface

I installed en_core_web_trf through clone:

```
!git clone https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf
```

Now I'm trying to run the following:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
```

Then get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\sg18551\Documents\Skunkworks Project\Automate Open-End Responses\new\ML Model.ipynb Cell 3 in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import spacy
----> 2 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")

File c:\Users\sg18551\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py:54, in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     30 def load(
     31     name: Union[str, Path],
     32     *,
   (...)
     37     config: Union[Dict[str, Any], Config] = util.SimpleFrozenDict(),
     38 ) -> Language:
     39     """Load a spaCy model from an installed package or a local path.
     40 
     41     name (str): Package name or model path.
   (...)
     52     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     53     """
---> 54     return util.load_model(
     55         name,
     56         vocab=vocab,
     57         disable=disable,
     58         enable=enable,
     59         exclude=exclude,
...
---> 79 return _unpackb(packed, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\sg18551\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\srsly\msgpack\_unpacker.pyx:191, in srsly.msgpack._unpacker.unpackb()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 1547: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to download and install `en_core_web_trf` is:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

The huggingface repo is a mirror for some of the more recent releases, but the primary way to install spacy trained pipelines is `spacy download`, and you can find all releases under https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases.

The huggingface repo does include all the same model data, but I suspect that you don't have `git lfs` installed so you're not downloading all the data when you clone the repo, or possibly a file was accidentally truncated. The whole directory should be ~2 GB total including the extra wheel file and the git history.

Comment: whenever i try run the above, i face the following issue:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

Comment: That sounds like a local networking issue? As a temporary workaround, you could try installing from the huggingface wheel URL instead: `pip install https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf/resolve/main/en_core_web_trf-any-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Similar issue - any solution for the networking issue: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /spacy/en_core_web_trf/resolve/main/en_core_web_trf-any-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

Comment: These errors are related to your local network or SSL configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After installing through git clone:
`!git clone https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf`

I installed the wheel file separately: `!python -m pip install en_core_web_trf-any-py3-none-any.whl`